# AsyncLayoutInflater with SharedElementTransition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I want to implement AsyncLayoutInflater alongside SharedElementTransition in fragments. Made it like below:

```
 asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, view as ViewGroup, { inflatedView, _, _ ->
        val binding = FragmentBinding.bind(inflatedView)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        view.addView(binding.root)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            binding.myImageView.transitionName = entity.name
        }
        startPostponedEnterTransition()
        displayInfo()
    })
```

But it doesn't work. Does someone know how I can implement it? Is it even possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using AsyncLayoutInflater?

If there is need in it then I think the best way is to make view with element that will be animated by transition and container where your layout will be inflated asynchronously (if async is needed) and inflate it synchronously. After that start async inflation of the rest of the view